# existence of a bounded $C^\infty$ function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

> Prove that there exists a bounded $C^\infty$ function (i.e. infinitely differentiable) $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(0) = \infty$.

The function $g:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=1/(1-x)$ has derivatives satisfying $g^{(n)}(0) = n!$, so we can let $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ for $|x| \leq \frac{1}2$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $|x| \ge 1/2$, provided we can find a function $h : \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ that is in $C^\infty$ with $h(x) = 1$ for $|x|\leq \frac{1}4$ and $h(x) = 0$ for $|x|\ge \frac{1}2$. Then $f'(0) = g'(0)h(0) + g(0) h'(0) = g'(0) = 0!$, and one can show by induction that $f^{(n)}(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i} g^{(n-i)}(x)h^{(i)}(x),$ from which it follows that $f^{(n)}(0) = g(0) = n!$ for each x.

> How do I find $h$? I tried using $\arctan$ but I can't even get a differentiable function (at least on all of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the constraints.

Comment: "How do I find $h$?" By opening Loring Tu's wonderful book [*An Introduction to Manifolds (Second Edition)*](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Manifolds-Second-Universitext/dp/1441973990/ref=sr_1_7?crid=3BDFVTDJAJ36C&keywords=An+Introduction+to+Manifolds+%28Second+Edition%29&qid=1646343118&sprefix=an+introduction+to+manifolds+second+edition+%2Caps%2C204&sr=8-7), on page 141. You will find there a portrait of $h$, an example of the class of functions appropriately called "bump functions", i.e. $C^\infty$ functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with compact support .

Answer (score 1):

You need a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). Here's an explicit one

$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
0&x\le -1\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{1}{x+1/2}+\frac{1}{x+1})}&-1\le x\le -\frac{1}{2}\\
1&-\frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{1}{1/2-x}+\frac{1}{1-x})}&\frac{1}{2}\le x\le 1\\
0&x\ge 1
\end{cases}$$

It looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wysr1ezr9t)

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on how you got that bump function?